# Visual C++ 2010, how to locate failing post build step?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to build a new to me Visual C++ project (building it from within the IDE), it compiles fine but looks like it fails in a post build step, see output below.  I want to somehow disable this step, but I can't find where it's defined.  I've done a text search of all the files but find no reference to the machine name sl-fc-1.  Where is this post build step being defined?

Thank you,
Fred

```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: appname, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  appname.cpp
1>  appname.vcxproj -> C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\Debug\appname.exe
1>  C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\Debug\appname.exe
1>  The network path was not found.
1>  C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\Debug\appname.ilk
1>  C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\Debug\appname.pdb
1>  The network path was not found.
1>  The network path was not found.
1>          0 file(s) copied.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\Debug\* \\sl-fc-1\appname\*
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: copy C:\projects\compname\tck\app\appname\\vslibs\* \\sl-fc-1\appname\*
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: should be defined in appname.vcproj

Comment: It was defined in there, I removed it, reopened VC++ and went to rebuild but am still getting the same error.  What else could be wrong?

Comment: Do you use source control? Is there any possibility for the vcproj file to be overwritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom build tasks can be in one of two places. Right click on your project, select Properties, then check:

1. Configuration Properties|Build Events|Post-Build Event
2. Configuration Properties|Custom Build Step|General

If you have multiple projects in your solution check all of them.
If you don't see a reference to a copy to \sl-fc-1 you may have a reference to a batch file that does this copy. I recommend that you disable all the post-build tasks one by one until you find the one that does this.

Good luck.